# Avoiding copy and paste bewteen two sheets when using R1C1 - do I have to stop using "With sheetname"?

Tags: excel, vba

I have been reading that it is better to avoid using copy and paste in VBA as it it much quicker to just make one range equal to another range.

But if I want to move data from one sheet to another using R1C1 references this seems to mean the code has to be a lot harder to read and understand.

If I would normally use:

```
With sheetOne
    .Range(.Cells(row1, col1), .Cells(row2, col2)).Copy
End With

With sheetTwo
    .Range(.Cells(row3, col3).address).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End With
```

Then the only way I can see to not use copy and paste is to reapeat the sheet names multiple times as I can't use `With` :

```
sheetTwo.Range(sheetTwo.Cells(row3, col3), sheetTwo.Cells(row4, col4)) = _
sheetOne.Range(sheetOne.Cells(row1, col1), sheetOne.Cells(row2, col2))
```

I prefer using `With` as it feels like waste repeating the sheet names like this, but if I'm going to stop using copy and paste do I have to go down the route of the second piece of code above?

Comment: Note that `.Range(.Cells(row3, col3).address).PasteSpecial` is the same as `.Cells(row3, col3).PasteSpecial`

Comment: Ah yes, I think I knew that, but I keep doing it the longer way for some reason. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually instead of this

```
sheetTwo.Range(sheetTwo.Cells(row3, col3), sheetTwo.Cells(row4, col4)) = _
sheetOne.Range(sheetOne.Cells(row1, col1), sheetOne.Cells(row2, col2))
```

You can do this

```
With sheetOne
    Dim SrcRange As Range
    Set SrcRange = .Range(.Cells(row1, col1), .Cells(row2, col2))
End With

With sheetTwo
    Dim DestRange As Range
    Set DestRange = .Range(.Cells(row3, col3), .Cells(row4, col4))
End With

DestRange.Value = SrcRange.Value
```

or

```
With sheetOne
    Dim SrcRange As Range
    Set SrcRange = .Range(.Cells(row1, col1), .Cells(row2, col2))
End With

With sheetTwo
    .Range(.Cells(row3, col3), .Cells(row4, col4)).Value = SrcRange.Value
End With
```